# What do the markings in the photos say about the flooring and it's quality?

Tags: hardwood-floor

What do the markings in the photos say about the flooring and it's quality?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only legible marking on the flooring itself is "PLAIN". This means unfinished.

The paper, assuming it goes with, is saying it's White Oak, 4" planks, "B" grade and the "R" probably means it is treated with a repellent of some kind.

The problem with deciphering what someone wrote is lingo varies even over very short distances, so what the person wrote might mean something different to different professionals.

Comment: Thanks,  I am new to stackExchange, Is there anything I need to do to acknowledge my question has been answered?

Comment: Well, me too so unfortunately I don't know. I started yesterday, I'll look

Comment: It says to click a checkmark by the asnwer

Comment: @STS1SS Accepting an answer (check mark) is the right thing to do.

Comment: Thanks sir. I started by asking a question, and then just started answering. Pretty broad experience so I can be helpful in a lot of areas.